# Where is the Production Editing Toolbar?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, editing, toolbar

I'm having trouble finding the production editing toolbar in arcgis 10.1. Is it part of an add on extension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am pretty sure it's a part of the Production Mapping extension. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//010300000214000000

This is not a free extention. (approx $9000) I don't think there is a free trial for this one ethier altough you might be able to contact your ESRI rep and see what you can do. At least it is not listed as the trial extentiosn in the installer.

Comment: correct around 10k after local taxes.